# file error in python

Tags: python

I have the following script:

```
import os
import stat

curDir = os.getcwd()+'/test'

for (paths, dirs, files) in os.walk(curDir):
        for f in files:
            if os.stat(f)[stat.ST_SIZE]>0:
                print f
```

and the folder test/:

```
test_folder:
    --test.wav
a.exe
t1
t2
rain.wav
```

when i run this script with geany it gives the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "new_folder_deleter.py", line 8, in <module>
>    if os.stat(f)[stat.ST_SIZE]>0:
>    OSError: [Errno2] No such file or directory: 'a.exe'
> ```

but when I run it with IDLE:
it just prints test.wav in subfolder test_folder

Can anyone explain why it is so and how I can fix it?
P.S:
My aim is to browse all files and delete files with specified sizes.

Comment: Have you tried doing this - os.stat( os.path.join(paths, f) ) instead of just os.stat( f )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a full path for `os.stat`, unless the file is in the current working directory. The simplest way to fix this is to change the WD before trying to access the files:

```
curDir = os.getcwd()+'/test'
os.chdir(curDir)
```

A more general solution is to pass the full path to `os.stat`:

```
if os.stat(os.path.join(paths, f))[stat.ST_SIZE]>0:
  print f
```

I am not quite sure why IDLE does not produce an error here, though.

Answer (score 0):

The `os.walk` function returns file and directory names relative to current folder, so you need to `os.stat(os.path.join(paths, f))`.

Answer (score 0):

The filename is only the basename. You need to use `os.path.join(path, f)`.

Answer (score 0):

The list of files that's returned in the `files` component from `os.walk()` is just the file names, without the path. Before you can perform any operations on those files (including `stat()`), you need to reassemble the path to the file.